# Gathering a portion of text on a webpage

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to gather a specific portion of text from a webpage.  Basically I want to try to gather this portion of text from http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/nwprod/thanks/index.thankusa.php:

> 70026 THKS 70133 THKS 70200 THKS 70219 THKS 70231 THKS 70261 THKS
>    70273 THKS 70308 THKS 70316 THKS 70326 THKS 70350 THKS 70361 THKS
>    70398 THKS 72201 THKS 72202 THKS 72206 THKS 72208 THKS 72210 THKS
>    72214 THKS 72215 THKS 72230 THKS 72233 THKS 72235 THKS 72240 THKS
>    72248 THKS 72249 THKS 72250 THKS 72251 THKS 72261 THKS 72265 THKS
>    72274 THKS 72293 THKS 72305 THKS 72317 THKS 72318 THKS 72327 THKS
>    72340 THKS 72357 THKS 72363 THKS 72364 THKS 72365 THKS 72376 THKS
>    72388 THKS 72402 THKS 72403 THKS 72426 THKS 72440 THKS 72451 THKS
>    72456 THKS 72469 THKS 72476 THKS 72489 THKS 72493 THKS 72501 THKS
>    72518 THKS 72520 THKS 72528 THKS 72558 THKS 72562 THKS 72572 THKS
>    72582 THKS 72597 THKS 72632 THKS 72634 THKS 72645 THKS 72649 THKS
>    72659 THKS 72662 THKS 72672 THKS 72681 THKS 72694 THKS 72712 THKS
>    72747 THKS 72764 THKS 72768 THKS 72776 THKS 72786 THKS 72797 THKS
>    74389 THKS 74455 AB   74494 THKS 74560 THKS 78526 THKS 91165 THKS
>    91212 THKS 91285 THKS 91334 THKS 91348 THKS 91376 THKS 91408 THKS
>    91413 abc  91765 THKS

so far I've got this bit of code with the intention of using an xpath to specify what section of text I want to gather:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/nwprod/thanks   /index.thankusa.php')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
test = tree.xpath('/html/body/table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font/pre')
```

however that's just returning this:
    [Element pre at 0x4240688]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) to get text contents of your tag:

```
contents = test[0].text_content()
```

Then you can process your string:

```
results = re.split('\n\s?\n', contents)[1]
```

Comment: @EvanKeeler if it helped you, you can accept this answer